# If array of objects is missing object from another array, push it to specific position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have one array of filtered objects:

```
const filteredArr = [
{name: "Prague - city", cityId: "111", type: "CITY"},
{name: "Prague - bus station", cityId: "111", type: "STATION"},
{name: "Prague - train station ", cityId: "111", type: "STATION"},

{name: "Brno - bus station", cityId: "333", type: "STATION"},
{name: "Brno - train station", cityId: "333", type: "STATION"},
]
```

And another array, which contains all cities:

```
    const citiesData = [ 
    {name: "Prague - city", cityId: "111", type: "CITY"},
    {name: "Brno", cityId: "333", type: "CITY"},
    {name: "Wien", cityId: "444", type: "CITY"}

// ANOTHER CITIES
    ]
```

Now I need to map over filteredArr and find if there is "CITY" which belong to "STATION".

If not I need to do following, so final result will look like:
Basically add CITY Object above first station.

```
const finalResult = [
{name: "Prague - city", cityId: "111", type: "CITY"},
{name: "Prague - bus station", cityId: "111", type: "STATION"},
{name: "Prague - train station ", cityId: "111", type: "STATION"},
{name: "Brno - city", cityId: "333", type: "CITY"}, // ADD THIS ONE ABOVE FIRST STATION
{name: "Brno - bus station", cityId: "333", type: "STATION"},
{name: "Brno - train station", cityId: "333", type: "STATION"}
]
```

Its little bit complex so feel free to adjust values if needed.

Comment: can the citiesData not have cities that are in filteredArr

Comment: @cmgchess yes, there will be like another 100 cities

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the item and if not found search for the group, either for the start/**CITY** or end/**STATION**.

```js
const
    update = (data, insert) => {
        const
            CITY = 'CITY',
            STATION = 'STATION';
            
        insert.forEach(o => {
            const keys = ['name', 'cityId', 'type'];
            if (data.find(q => keys.every(k => o[k] === q[k]))) return;
            let index = -1;
            switch (o.type) {
            
                case STATION:
                    index = data.findIndex((q, i, a) => o.cityId === q.cityId && q.type === CITY && (a.length === i + 1 || a[i + 1].cityId !== o.cityId));
                    if (index !== -1) index++; // insert after index
                    break;
                    
                case CITY:
                    index = data.findIndex(q => o.cityId === q.cityId && q.type === STATION);
                    
            }
            if (index === -1) data.push(o);
            else data.splice(index, 0, o);
        });
        return data;
    },
    filteredArr = [{ name: "Prague - city", cityId: "111", type: "CITY"}, { name: "Prague - bus station", cityId: "111", type: "STATION"}, { name: "Prague - train station ", cityId: "111", type: "STATION"}, { name: "Brno - bus station", cityId: "333", type: "STATION"}, { name: "Brno - train station", cityId: "333", type: "STATION"}],
    citiesData = [
        { name: "Prague - city", cityId: "111", type: "CITY" },
        { name: "Brno", cityId: "333", type: "CITY" },
        { name: "Foo", cityId: "444", type: "CITY" },
        { name: "Bar-1", cityId: "555", type: "STATION" },
        { name: "Bar-2", cityId: "555", type: "STATION" },
        { name: "Foo-1", cityId: "444", type: "STATION" },
        { name: "Bar", cityId: "555", type: "CITY" },
    ];

console.log(update(filteredArr, citiesData));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```